# Vue prop is undefined for a moment when page is reloaded

Tags: vue.js, pinia

I have a parent component that retrieves a todo item from a pinia store, based on the current vue router params `/todo/123`, and passes it into a child component as a prop.

The app works properly when navigating to the component using router-links. Except when I refresh the page while I am in a TodoViewComponent page `(localhost:5173/todo/123)`. When I refresh the page, the props are `undefined` initially, hence throwing me an error.

```
Proxy(Object) {todo: undefined}
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
Proxy(Object) {todo: Proxy(Object)}
```

What would be the solution so that the `SingleTodoComponent` receives the todo prop "instantaneously" upon page reload?

TodoViewComponent (parent):

```js
<script setup>
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import { computed } from 'vue';

import SingleTodoComponent from '@/components/SingleTodoComponent.vue';
import { useTodos } from '@/stores/todosStore';

const route = useRoute()
const todosStore = useTodos()

const todo = computed(() => todosStore.todos.find(t => {
    return t.id === parseInt(route.params.todoId)
}))
</script>

<template>
            <SingleTodoComponent :todo="todo"></SingleTodoComponent>
</template>
```

SingleTodoComponent:

```js
<script setup>
const props = defineProps(['todo'])

console.log(props)

const formState = reactive({
    id: props.todo.id,
    content: props.todo.content_en,
    bookmarked: props.todo.bookmarked,
    completed: props.todo.completed,
    date_deadline: props.todo.date_deadline
})
</script>
```

Comment: Data is retrieved asynchronously, so your components need to be written to cope with missing data while it's being retrieved.  Check that objects exist before trying to access their properties and show a loading indicator or blank state if it doesn't; the components will re-render once the data arrives.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly passing `todo` as a prop, you can pass a loading state as a prop until the `todo` is fetched from the store.

TodoViewComponent:

```
<script setup>
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
import { computed, ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

import SingleTodoComponent from '@/components/SingleTodoComponent.vue';
import { useTodos } from '@/stores/todosStore';

const route = useRoute();
const todosStore = useTodos();

const loading = ref(true);

const todo = computed(() => todosStore.todos.find(t => {
    return t.id === parseInt(route.params.todoId)
}));

onMounted(() => {
    // Once the component is mounted, set loading to false
    loading.value = false;
});
</script>

<template>
    <SingleTodoComponent :todo="todo" :loading="loading"></SingleTodoComponent>
</template>
```

SingleTodoComponent:

```
<script setup>
import { defineProps, ref, onMounted, reactive } from "vue";

const props = defineProps(['todo', 'loading']);

const formState = ref({
    id: null,
    content: '',
    bookmarked: false,
    completed: false,
    date_deadline: ''
});

onMounted(() => {
    if (!props.loading) {
        formState.value = {
            id: props.todo.id,
            content: props.todo.content_en,
            bookmarked: props.todo.bookmarked,
            completed: props.todo.completed,
            date_deadline: props.todo.date_deadline
        };
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Async process: you have no todo onMounted child.
Simple way to test - use <SingleTodoComponent  v-if="todo" :todo="todo"></SingleTodoComponent>